# Asymptotics of $\max\limits_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}X_k/n$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

I found an assertion in [this paper](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDoQFjAA&url=http://www.secura-re.com/secura/pdf/withpeer/Ladoucette%255B4%255D.pdf&ei=HXpdUaMK58vQBZeVgIAD&usg=AFQjCNHVBVsIEa-Sep8J1idBH5FUuCYeUQ&sig2=mb3kQg3zbPeLL2JHcclDQw&bvm=bv.44770516,d.d2k&cad=rja) at the beginning of page 6, but i can't see how to justify it: Let $X_n \geq 0$ i.i.d. with finite expectation then:
$$ \frac1n\max\limits_{k \leq n}X_k \to 0 \quad\text{almost surely as  } \,n \to \infty$$

As Davide posted [there is convergence in probability to zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264962/convergence-in-distribution-to-zero). I was wondering if it is evident that we have **almost sure** convergence also.

Comment: I don't assume finite variance :)

Comment: And how do we get almost sure convergence? From the other question I can get only convergence in probability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Let $M_n=n^{-1}\cdot\max\limits_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}X_k$ for some nonnegative identically distributed integrable sequence $(X_n)_n$, then $M_n\to0$ almost surely. (The independence of the sequence $(X_n)_n$ is not needed.)

To prove this, let $x\gt0$. If $X_n\leqslant nx$ for every $n$ large enough, say for every $n\geqslant N$, then $nM_n\leqslant NM_N+nx$ for every $n\geqslant N$ and in particular $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}M_n\leqslant x$. Thus,
$$
[\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}M_n\geqslant2x]\subseteq A_x,\qquad A_x=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}A^n_x,\qquad A^n_x=[X_n\geqslant nx].
$$
The sequence $(X_n)_n$ is identically distributed, hence
$$
\sum_{n\geqslant1}P[A_x^n]=\sum_{n\geqslant1}P[X_1\geqslant nx]\leqslant x^{-1}E[X_1],
$$
which is finite. By Borel-Cantelli lemma (easy part), $P[A_x]=0$. This holds for every $x\gt0$ hence $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}M_n=0$ almost surely. Since every $M_n\geqslant0$ almost surely, the conclusion follows.

**Edit:** To show the upper bound of the series, note that, for every nonnegative $\xi$,
$$
\sum_{n\geqslant1}\mathbf 1_{\xi\geqslant nx}=\lfloor x^{-1}\xi\rfloor\leqslant x^{-1}\xi,
$$
and integrate this pointwise inequality over $\xi$ with respect to the distribution of $X_1$.

Comment: That does it :) . I knew it had to be a Borel-Cantellish argument but I didn't arrive to anything. Thanks!